# Add categories and posts to page hierarchy

Tags: pages

So, I find myself in this situation now and again, trying to solve a particular workflow. I have a page hierarchy something like this:

```
Page 1
    Sub-page 1 (category term listing)
        Post 1
        Post 2
    Sub-page 3 (standard page)
Page 2 (category term listing)
    Post 5
    Post 6
```

Now the particular problem is that I want to maintain this hierarchical structure, particularly in the breadcrumbs and url (friendly rewrites). Basically I want category and post pages to appear in the page hierarchy, for example `/Page 1/Sub-page 1/Post 1/`, rather than the wordpress default: `/category/{category-name}` and `/blog/{post-name}`.

Is this just something WordPress won't do, or does anyone have any clever workarounds?

Comment: It's not clever so much as a nightmare, but have you looked at [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)? You can make up any permalink structure you want with the right filters and actions.

Comment: agreed, sounds like fun.

Comment: Ten years and no answer to this? I've been trying for... dang, three full days now... logic says this simple, obvious functionality should be possible but I can't find any working code for it anywhere.